# SQL - Group By with a subselect?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DATEPART(hh, CallStart)), DATEPART(hh, CallStart) as 'Hour'
  FROM PhoneSystemLog 
 WHERE MONTH(CallStart) = @Month and YEAR(CallStart) = @Year 
 GROUP BY DATEPART(hh, CallStart)
```

This is fine, it will group the number of calls made per hour, but what I want to do is then group calls made between 12am - 7am into a group and those made from 6pm - 12am into a group as there aren't many made at those times so it seems pointless to have the number of calls made every hour for those hours (As they're out of business hours). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `case` to translate hour to period:

```
select  Period
,       count(*) as Calls
from    (
        select  case 
                when datepart(hh, CallStart) between 0 and 7 then '1-7'
                when datepart(hh, CallStart) between 18 and 23 then '18-24'
                else cast(datepart(hh, CallStart) as varchar(2))
                end as Period
        from    PhoneSystemLog
        where   MONTH(CallStart) = @Month 
                and YEAR(CallStart) = @Year 
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        Period
```

Comment: +1 for not having to repeat the case in the select and the group by.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff: for ordering you can use (this is sql server syntax):=                                                                                                                                            order by cast(case when charindex('-',Period,1)>0 then substring(Period,1,charindex('-',Period,1)-1) 
                           else Period end as int)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
select count(DATEPART(hh, CallStart)), 
    CASE 
    when DATEPART(hh, callstart) between 0 to 7 then '12:00AM-7AM'
    when DATEPART(hh, callstart) between 18 to 23 then '06PM-12AM'
    END
as 'hour' from PhoneSystemLog  
where MONTH(callstart) = @Month and YEAR(callstart) = @Year  
group by 
    CASE 
    when DATEPART(hh, callstart) between 0 to 7 then '12:00AM-7AM'
    when DATEPART(hh, callstart) between 18 to 23 then '06PM-12AM'
    END
```